# como saber si un documento que estoy por ingresar en mongodb ya existe?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

necesito saber si ha alguna manera de poder verificar si un documento existe antes de guardarlo en mongodb a travez de mongoose

```
const newSchema = new Schema({
  usuario: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjetId,
    ref: 'usuarios
  }],
  de: {type: String, require: true}
)}
```

habra algun metodo para verificar si hay un documento con los mismos datos que se estan por ingresar??

Comment: Exactamente ¿qué deseas verificar?. Tu esquema tiene 2 campos: `usuarios` de tipo `Array` y `de` de tipo `String`. Un documento de ese esquema puede almacenar muchos valores en el campo `usuarios`. No entiendo lo que pretendes lograr con la validación. ¿Quieres evitar elementos repetidos en `usuarios`? ¿Quieres evitar que exista más de un documento con el mismo valor en el campo `de`? Si puedes aclarar cuál sería un documento único y cómo lo estás salvando, entonces tal vez podríamos hallar una solución. Saludos

Comment: Mí intención es que antes de que se guarden los datos verificar si hay un objeto con los mismos datos, si los hay entonces no lo guardo, si no hay entonces lo guardo, me explico?